# Windows Vista Icon Library

Tags: visual-studio, icons, windows-vista

I want to use Windows Vista style icons (original Vista Icons, not some "replicas") in my application.
I know that Visual Studio 2015/2017 comes with an icon library, however I don't like the icons and I'd like to use the "older" Vista style icons.
I also know that <del>VS2012</del>**VS2010** Professional came with a Vista style icon library, however <del>VS2012</del>**VS2010** is no longer available and I don't have access to it.

Where do I get those icons from?

Comment: have you downloaded the zip? are the images you want in the zip or not? Later this week I'll delete the zip from my dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Image libraries can be still downloaded from [Microsoft download center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825)

Download and extract the `VS2012 Image Library.zip` to get the older icons.

Ok, the 2010 is not available to download. I've uploaded the `VS2010ImageLibrary.zip` to my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z40hnqef83kf0yw/VS2010ImageLibrary.zip?dl=1).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was wrong about the VS version (I edited my question accordingly). VS2012 already came with modern icons. I need VS2010 icons.